# OnsenUIで複数ページを使用するときの戻るボタンが実装できない

Tags: javascript, monaca, html, onsen-ui

こんにちは。
Monacaのアプリ製作プラットフォームを使っています。
使用しているJSフレームワークは、OnsenUI V2 JS Minimumです。
OnsenUIで複数ページを設定して、飛ぶ先のページに × のようにページを消して戻る仕組みを作っています。具体的には、index.html→page1.html→index.htmlという風に母体のindex.htmlに戻れるようにしたいです。
実際に以下のコードをpage1.htmlに組み込みましたが、ボタンも現れませんでした。参考にしたサイトはこちら http://matorel.com/archives/754 です。サイト内では、ボタンのデザインを外部ウェブサイト掲載の物を使用していたようでしたので、個人的に用意した画像を代わりに試してみましたが、そちらも反映されませんでした。
原因は他にあるのでしょうか？Onsenに関してまだ知識も浅く、学習過程にあるので、今回の問題やそれ以外の内容でもご指摘やアドバイスをお待ちしております。
よろしくお願いします。

HTML

```
<ons-page>
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button>
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-close-round" fixed-width="false" style="font-size: 60px; vertical-align: -4px"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
</ons-toolbar>    
</ons-page>
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/93625

Answer (score 0):

ons-back-buttonを使ってみてはいかがでしょうか